# Database query working fine on localhost but not working properly on server

Tags: laravel

My Database query working fine on the localhost but now working on the server. I am using laravel 6.

```
function fetch_data(Request $request)
{
 if($request->ajax()) 
 {
     
  $sort_by = $request->get('sortby');
  $sort_type = $request->get('sorttype');
        $query = $request->get('query');
        $query = str_replace(" ", "%", $query);
  $data = DB::table('fontawesomeicons')
                ->where('id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('icon_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('icon_code', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
                ->orderBy($sort_by, $sort_type)
                ->paginate(50);
  return view('icons_table_data', compact('data'))->render();
 }
}
```

Comment: It helps to see the actual error message MySQL returns - see if that's in error logs...
Other than that...
1. check database table and fields - in case you missed something
2. if localhost is Windows, check the Case of table and field names

Comment: working absolutely fine on localhost

Comment: What is the output of `$request->get('query');`?